# What should an ember-data REST server API return?

Tags: api, http, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm having weird update errors on some routes so I just wanted to sure that it wasn't something fundamental at this level.

At the moment I do this:

```
Create   POST       /plural        201    {"singular": {"id":"1", ...}} 
FindAll  GET        /plural        200    {"plural": [{"id":"1",... },{"id":"2", ...    
Find     GET        /plural/1      200    {"singular": {"id":"1", ...}} 
Update   PUT/PATCH  /plural/1      200    {"singular": {"id":"1", ...}} 
Delete   DELETE     /plural/1      200    (empty)
```

I serve 404s or 400s depending on whether the route looks good.

Is this to spec as far as you can see?

Answer (score 1):

You should use correct http status codes for your cases. [This page](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) has good explanations.

404 : If the path (eg. /plural) is not available.

422 : If the request is erronous.
[Ember Data guide](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html) says it works good with 422. Also search for 422 in [this site](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html).

204 No Content: If no data returned. (Such as deletion.)

Further, if you want have a check [JSON API Specs](http://jsonapi.org/format/#error-objects):